# iOS 7.1 simulator drag and drop not working in XCode 6.1?

Tags: ios, xcode, drag-and-drop, ios-simulator

After upgrading XCode to v6.1 I find I can no longer drag a HTML file from finder onto iOS simulator 7.1 and have it start. This still works with the iOS 8.1 simulator, just not 7.1. This doesn't seem to be a known bug (can't find anything in search) so does anyone know how to make drag & drop work again?